# geom_smooth function error with loess method in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, smoothing, geom

I'm doing a plot with ggplot2 but when I add the function geom_smooth with method = loess, my graph doesn't work . Indeed, it creates curves that don't match with data.
When I change this line in my script, by deleting it , or using another method , graphs work correctly.

I already checked that my data are numeric and that there are not extrem values because of a missing decimal, but it is not that.

How can I correct that to make my geom_smooth work with the loess method ?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including some code that produces sample data. For instance you could run `dput(donnees_tot_g` and paste the output into the body of your question.

Comment: ... and please provide the code for `method="loess"`, the case that doesn't work, as well as the code for `method="lm"`, the case that does.

Comment: My guess is that you're confusing `geom_smooth(method="loess")` doesn't work (i.e., produces a wrong answer) with `geom_smooth(method="loess")` doesn't produce what I hoped it would.   It could "work", but not produce the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the default parameters of the `loess` are not working well for your dataset. You have only a small number of discrete `x` values so it doesn't know how best to fit it. For example, if you look at the default value of `span` in `base::loess()` (which `ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = "loess")` calls under the hood) you can find that the default value is `span = 0.75`. If you just increase to `span = 0.8` you get what I assume is closer to what you wanted. For more on the `span` parameter you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197552/13210554) answer.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = quantity, y = fecundity, col = color)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.8, alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.1,0.3,0.6,0.9,1.5), limits=c(0.1,1.5))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("20S" = "aquamarine1","25S" = "aquamarine3","28S" =
                                 "aquamarine4","20Y" = "darkgoldenrod1","25Y" = "darkgoldenrod3", "28Y" = "darkgoldenrod4"))+
  ggtitle("Fécondité en fonction du traitement de nourriture et de la température")+
  xlab("Quantité nutritionnelle") + ylab("Fécondité (nb d'oeufs/femelle)")+
  theme_grey(base_size = 22)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote the method type, e.g. use  `geom_smooth(method="loess")`

Comment: I already tried to quote the method type but this doesn't change everything